# Should I use MultiSite for a subdomain based wp site?

Tags: multisite, users

I know the question is asked alot of times, but what I am trying to create is a network under the same site.

example.com
a.example.com
b.example.com
a.b.example.com

and it goes on. With example.com being the main site, some of the subdomains will be redirecting to ceratin categories of post from main site, some more will be redirecting to a site with toaly different theme from main site and custom functions. One more site being shop and one central place to edit profile with all details.

I wants users to be synced between all site. Should I use multisite or use bridges with different site for each ?
The network is going to be something like stackexchange, just that its not a q and a site.

The site will be a tech site, providing news, forums, tutorials, plugins by site and etc. The only thing all the sites will share commonly is the color scheme and maybe the top header.

It's not completely a WP dependent site, through as far as I have mapped out, WP has more roles in it and it is also easy for me to write plugins for majority of the site.

diply.com is one example for posts. tomshardware on forums.

Is there something already out there for wordpress ? even if not, can I achieve it with wordpress as base ?

Comment: What is "bridges"? That doesn't sound like a typical WP term to me.

Comment: i used to connect xenforo and wordpress users.. they call it bridges. A bridge to share the user data between both the sites

Comment: unity3d.com site is also a clone. They use main site, forums, question and answers all connected together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated your use case seems suitable:

- multiple sites — check
- shared users — check

WP multisite does this.

However there aren't that many details in your question beyond that. It is a guesswork to recommend for or against it for such a complicated site, without knowing requirements thoroughly.

Comment: edited it :D Please check

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on how many sites you want to update. I don't have a lot of sites to manage so I went with individual installs. Most of the updates are automatic these days so everything is easy. I can also test where bugs are easily having different sites. You might need a lot of space though, doing what I do.

Comment: I wanna make it as simple as possible in backend settings.